# How can I test a function working or not in pl-sql?

Tags: oracle, function, debugging, plsqldeveloper

I learned the basics of writing a function and procedure in pl-sql but I don't know how to test if it's working , and if not How can I debug it .
Any Ideas please .
thanks all. 
 Here is the function I'm trying to test it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MIN_MAX_SAL RETURN NUMBER AS 
cursor emp_cur is select salary from employees ;
emp_sal number;
min_sal jobs.min_salary%type;
max_sal jobs.max_salary%type;
BEGIN
select min_salary , max_salary into min_sal , max_sal from jobs;
for emp_sal in emp_cur loop
if (emp_sal > max_sal or emp_sal < min_sal) then
return 0;
end loop;
RETURN 1;
END MIN_MAX_SAL;
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 11):

In general, like the question - how to run/test in SQL*Plus...

To test a function that takes scalar arguments and returns a scalar value:

```
SELECT function_name(parm1, parm2) FROM DUAL;
```

To test a procedure:

```
EXEC procedure_name(parm1, parm2)
```

If the procedure returns a `REFCURSOR` or `SYS_REFCURSOR` by way of an `OUT` parameter:

```
VAR x REFCURSOR
EXEC procedure_name(parm1, parm2, :x)
PRINT x
```

The colon before the `x` in the second line above is required. It's not allowed in the other two lines (`VAR` and `PRINT`).

If you're having trouble with testing a specific function or procedure in SQL*Plus, please post the function/proc or at the very least its declaration.

To debug, sprinkle `DBMS_Output.Put_Line` calls at places where you want to check values. The `DBMS_Output` package is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm). Before running a proc with `DBMS _Output` calls, type the following at the SQL*Plus command line:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 50000
```

The `SIZE` is the number of characters that Oracle will allow `DBMS_Output` to echo. All output is sent back *after* the procedure is finished.